# Do t-stats created with robust standard errors follow a t-distribution in finite samples?

Tags: econometrics, heteroskedasticity, hypothesis-testing

I am creating econometrics notes and proved that, with normally distributed errors, homoskedasticity, and no serial correlation, t-stats based on baseline OLS standard errors do in fact follow a t-distribution.

I was trying to prove that, in the heteroskedastic, no serial correlation case with normally distributed errors, that t-stats based on robust standard errors follow a t-distribution. I was really struggling, then remembered that robust standard errors are known to be biased in finite samples (an example of a paper is [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016517651200047X)).

Is it the case that there is not a general result regarding the distribution of a t-stat created from robust standard errors in a finite sample? Stata reports t-stats rather than z-scores, so I'm not sure.

Comment: A robust t-stat does not have a t distribution in finite samples.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. That sounds right. Feel free to make this an answer rather than a comment, however for an "answer" they may expect a reference or some more of an explanation.